# Does the new UAE work visa policy benefit other visit visa holders?

Tags: visa, working, uae

If someone goes to UAE with a visit visa and then starts looking for jobs. In this case, he may have to stay for a long time. Is there any benefit for such job seekers in the recent work visa policy announced by UAE?

Comment: The new "green visa" program was just announced and hasn't started yet. It sounds like you're asking if there are benefits for someone who comes on a visitor visa and is looking for work? is that your question?

Comment: I have the same concern as @ZachLipton. I have edited your question's title to reflect what I think you're asking. If my edit is not correct or helpful, then you can "revert" my edit to show your original wording: to do so, use the "edited x minutes/hours/days ago" link above my name which appears under the question text.